# How is async network I/O handled with a WP7 Scheduled Task?

Tags: windows-phone-7

With Mango, it's possible to create a scheduled task to update the ShellTiles data.

It's up to the task to call `NotifyComplete()` when it's done.

Given that I/O on the phone should be asynchronous, how do you ensure that your I/O is complete prior to calling `NotifyComplete()`?

Via synchronization primatives? Or will the I/O be allowed to complete once the Task has notified the phone's OS it's complete?

Sync primatives is the obvious answer, but on the phone, blocking isn't really a good choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scheduled tasks are not executed synchronously. They are started and then have 15 seconds to call `NotifyComplete` (or abort) before they are forcefully terminated.

In direct answer to your question, you would use the asynchronous IO methods and then call `NotifyComplete` from the complete event or callback.

Here's an example. I've used the `Microsoft.Phone.Reactive` stuff but you can use Begin/EndGetResponse in the traditional way if you prefer.

```
public class SampleTask : ScheduledTaskAgent
{
    protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://stackoverflow.com");

        Observable.FromAsyncPattern<WebResponse>(
                request.BeginEndResponse,
                request.EndGetResponse
            )()
            .Subscribe(response =>
            {
                // Process the response
                NotifyComplete();

            }, ex =>
            {
                // Process the error
                Abort(); // Unschedules the task (if the exception indicates 
                         // the task cannot run successfully again)
            });

        // Synchronous control flow will continue and exit the OnInvoke method
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't always call Abort() on failure, it unschedules the task until the app is run again. You do not want to do that just because there is a patchy network connection on one update.

Comment: @Chris - Agreed, I was just trying to illustrate the options. I've added a comment to clear that up.